# Trouble merging 2 rasters using qgis

Tags: qgis, merge

I am trying to merge two rasters using the "merge" tool on Qgis 2.6.
Qgis does complete the process, but the resulting image only shows one of the two rasters with the rest of the extent with really negative values (black)...
Is there another way to merge?
I added a screenshot of the dialogbox/configuration and one of the resulting raster.

[image: screenshot 1: dialogbox/configuration]
[image: screenshot 2: resulting raster]
[image: values]

Comment: Did you try changing the color range on the merged raster? I wonder if it would illustrate what might be going wrong.

Comment: I will add a printscreen of that... 
The values of the black pixels are -3000 :(

Comment: Just a thought, but could you try ticking the `layer stack` option to see if it produces a different result? According to docs (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html ) it should "Place each input file into a separate stacked band."